# Selenium webdriver is missing click in headless firefox

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, ubuntu, firefox, headless

I have a selenium test that is written in python (3.5.2) using Firefox (v59.0.2 64-bit) on Ubuntu Linux (16.04.4 LTS).  The geckodriver version is v0.20.1.  I am automating a tweet on Twitter, and in GUI mode it works perfectly everytime.  However in headless mode it misses the same click on a specific element every time.  Has anyone seen this before? Also any suggestions for debugging in headless mode?

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec

# Here is the way I am getting the element
@property
def sending_message_close_button(self):
    self._sending_tweets_message_close = self._driver.wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                                                                             "div.alert-messages.js-message-drawer-visible a.Icon.Icon--close.Icon--medium.dismiss")))
    return self._sending_tweets_message_close
```

And here is the call to click the element in a method in the same class:

```
self.sending_message_close_button.click()
```

I have tried using ActionBuilder to move to the element and click on it.  I have also tried a javascript click.  Neither worked.

Here is how I am initializing the browser (url's redacted for privacy):

```
@property
def webdriver(self):
    if self._webdriver is None:
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument('-headless')
        profile = FirefoxProfile()
        profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 2)
        if self._env == 'demo':
            profile.set_preference("network.proxy.autoconfig_url", "")
        elif self._env == 'stage':
            profile.set_preference("network.proxy.autoconfig_url", "")
        profile.set_preference("network.proxy.no_proxies_on", "localhost")
        if self._use_options:
            self._webdriver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, options=options)
        else:
            self._webdriver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
        self._webdriver.implicitly_wait(10)
    return self._webdriver
```

Comment: how are you initialising the headless browser ?

Comment: I added the driver initialization here last week @cruisepandey